# without login project url should not work in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

am new to groovy am created small login page and landing page in grails using GGTS its working fine but if i copy paste any url its directly redirecting to the page my requirement is without login its should not redirect to any other page except login page 
i created 2 pages for login purpose first is username if its valid then that goes to password page, if that valid that shold redirect to landing page
now if i paste password page or landing page url that should not work without login with username, that should show error message like plz login in to proceed..how to do this one???

Comment: Use grails filters.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Spring Security Core](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#introduction). I don't know if you're using grails 2 or 3, but Spring Security Core is available for both, you just need to get the right version.

By default Spring Security Core allows only access to the index page, the other pages will be forbidden. To allow access for logged in users you would need to add `@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` annotations to your controller's actions. You could also allow access without logging in by adding `@Secured('permitAll')` to some actions or views.